# How can I share save games between multiple PCs?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How can I share a savegame for Dwarf Fortress between multiple computers (laptop and desktop)?  Can one instance of Dwarf Fortress run graphics and the other not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  When you "Save and Quit" the game is saved to the hard drive.  This can be uploaded to other computers.  DwarfFortress.exe uses the folder path specified in its config file to look for saves on your computer.  It's worth noting that you do need identical "world" files as well or the game will crash.

The easiest way I've found to do this is to use a software versioning system (such as SVN or GIT) and version the entire folder.  This will have the added benefit of indexing your saves and allowing you to go back to previous save points.

Your graphics set does not need to be the same.  In fact, on a single computer you do not have to have a consistent graphics set between saves.  You do, however, need to make sure your config file correctly identifies the graphics set you plan to use.

Sharing saves between different people is known as a Bloodline game.  Some famous ones can be found [here](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Category:Bloodline_Games). [Boatmurdered](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Boatmurdered) being one of the most famous.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *infamous*?  But yes, I use SVN to keep track of it now.  Smart guy that StrongAxe.

Comment: I used to use SVN, but I've found I like GIT better.  SVN tends to be more painful for merges (ie. I rewrite my config file and want it represented everywhere).

Comment: @C.Ross, @tzenes what hosting provider do you use?

Comment: @antony.trupe I Host it on a Linux server at my house.  This is great for at home, and I don't even try when I'm away.  @tzenes I only version my save folder, so I can run graphics in one place and not the other, etc.

Comment: SVN has the nice property that any subfolder can act as the head of a repository.  So for a while I had the entire thing on an SVN repo so I could bootstrap a new comp, and just updated the save folder.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com)! The easiest way is just to drop the entire Dwarf Fortress folder into the Dropbox folder. This would also make it easy to share with others, since you can make Dropbox folders publicly or small-group accessible. (Of course this doesn't allow you to have different configurations, but you might be able to modify my setup for your needs.)